# Less than Nothing

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request

I was wondering whether there is a *stronger* `Nothing` or whether this can easily be constructed. By stronger I mean the following:

If we have `Table[Nothing,{i,1,3}]` it will return `{}`. If we write `Table[Nothing,{i,1,3},{j,1,3}]` it will return `{{},{},{}}`. The `Nothing` cannot delete these lists since it is no longer there. Often I do want a list like this to collapse to `{}`. Practically, there is a very easy solution to retrieve the output I wish (such as `{}->Nothing`), but mostly I'm just curious for a solution of this type.

The new `nothing` would differ from `Nothing` in that `{nothing}` -> `nothing` if `{nothing}` is an element of a list (instead of to `{}`).

P.S. To clarify the objective: the new `nothing` would be applied to get nice lists without empty lists for objects like `Table[If[cnd[i],x[i],nothing,nothing],{i,1,n},{j,1,m}]`.

---

I am close to an answer with

```
nothing /: List[nothing] := nothing;
nothing /: List[a__, nothing] := List[a];
nothing /: List[nothing, b__] := List[b];
```

which I think is acceptable for me. However, it gets the wrong result for the outer list `{nothing}`->`nothing` if the whole thing turns out filled with nothing but `nothing`'s.

How do I define an object so that it has a different definition depending on whether it is contained in a list or not?

Comment: I don't think there's anything really built in, but a small tweak to your stuff will do it: `nothing /: List[a__, nothing, b___] := List[a, b]; nothing /: List[a___, nothing, b__] := List[a, b];`. Note the addition of triple underscores. That's actually important. By the way, you'll want to wrap those up-values in `HoldPattern` for if you want to tweak at all.

Comment: @MB1965 Nice. Yes of course, great with the double underscores on one side and triple on the other so that "nothing" always vanishes if paired with something else, otherwise it would get stuck in the middle. How exactly do I use HoldPattern (if you have the time, otherwise I will find out on my own)? I take it the purpose would be to avoid evaluating the upvalues on the left hand side of definitions.

Comment: use it around the entire pattern, e.g. `nothing /: HoldPattern[List[a___, nothing, b__]] := List[a, b];`. Prevents `List[a___, nothing, b__]` from evaluating to `List[a___, b__]` but matches `List[a___, nothing, b__]`. If you check the `*Values` for a function you'll see this is how they're stored.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to specify explicitly how many levels of empty `List`s you wish to remove, for example:

```
ClearAll[nothing]
nothing /: List[nothing[0] ..] := {};
nothing /: List[nothing[i_Integer] ..] := nothing[i - 1];
nothing /: List[a___, nothing[i_Integer], b___] := List[a, b];
```

Now

```
Table[nothing[0], {i, 1, 3}]
Table[If[EvenQ[i], i, nothing[0]], {i, 1, 5}]
Table[nothing[1], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
Table[If[EvenQ[i], i, nothing[1]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
Table[nothing[2], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}]
Table[If[EvenQ[i], i, nothing[2]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}]
```

> ```
> {}
>
> {2, 4}
>
> {}
>
> {{2, 2, 2}}
>
> {}
>
> {{{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}}
> ```

In the above `nothing[0]` is an equivalent of `Nothing` (doesn't remove `{}`), `nothing[1]` removes only `{}`, `nothing[2]` removes also `{{}}` etc.

---

If the goal is just to get nice-looking output, then solution is very simple:

```
ClearAll[nothing]
Format[nothing] = {};
nothing /: List[nothing ..] := nothing;
nothing /: List[a___, nothing, b___] := List[a, b];
```

Now

```
Table[nothing, {i, 1, 3}]
Table[If[EvenQ[i], i, nothing], {i, 1, 5}]
Table[nothing, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
Table[If[EvenQ[i], i, nothing], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
Table[nothing, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}]
Table[If[EvenQ[i], i, nothing], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}]
```

> ```
> {}
>
> {2, 4}
>
> {}
>
> {{2, 2, 2}}
>
> {}
>
> {{{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}}
> ```

Note however that it is just how the output is formatted for displaying in the FrontEnd, in the Kernel we have another expression:

```
out = Table[nothing, {i, 1, 3}]
FullForm[out]
```

> ```
> {}
>
> nothing
> ```

Also it will collapse enclosing `List`s as well:

```
{Table[nothing, {i, 1, 3}]}
{{Table[nothing, {i, 1, 3}]}}
```

> ```
> {}
>
> {}
> ```